# GA4 Data Stream URL

Tags: tags, analytics

Does the Stream URL matter with a GA4 data stream? It seems not but trying to understand why both Stream Name and Stream URL are available fields. With cross-domain tracking you can specify additional domains with no relation to the Stream URL.

Asking due to building web connected desktop applications without a URL.